# Displaying custom product attributes based on customer group (Magento)

Tags: magento, store, custom-attributes

I have wholesale attributes for certain products under one store in Magento. I would like to set it so those particular attributes only appear on the product page IF the customer is logged in and they are in the Wholesale customer group.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work, although I have not tested this together. It's assuming your wholesale groupid = 2 and that you want to show the product attribute 'productvideos'

```
app/design/frontend/default//template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

```
    if($_isLoggedIn === true){
      $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
      if($_myGroupId == 2){
        print $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductvideos(), 'productvideos');
      }
    }
```

Credit:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22597/#t74992

Comment: That did not appear to work, unfortunately. Here's the latest code I've got:

    <?php  
     $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
     if($_isLoggedIn == true){
          $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
          if($_myGroupId == 2){
          //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $this->htmlEscape($_product->getNumPerBox()), 'number_per_box');
          }
        }
    ?>

I also edited Mage>Catalog>Model>Product.php to include a function but it returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's the solution.

In template/catalog/product/view> attributes.phtml use the following:

```
<?php       
    $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
    if($_isLoggedIn == true){
      $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
      if($_myGroupId == 2){
        echo '<td class="label">Attribute Name/Label</td>';
        echo '<td class="label">';
        if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)):
          echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        endif;
        echo '</td>';
      }
    }
?>
```

Thanks to @nvoyageur for the initial pointer in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to be of service... thanks for posting a final solution that really works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same use case and I used the [GroupsCatalog](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vinai/extension/635/netzarbeiter_groupscatalog) extension, which is free and works perfectly for me.

Comment: Link redirects to the Magento Commerce home page.

Comment: I see! Either the extension has been discontinued or its [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paymentfilter-for-products-and-customer-groups.html) one.